# How to set Key of a Tabpage programatically?

Tags: c#, winforms, tabcontrol, tabpage

How to set Key for a tabpage

I have a tabcontrol1 in which i am adding a tabpage programatically.

```
TabPage tabpagep1=new TabPage("");
tabpagep1.Name = "tp1";
tabpage1.text="netabpage1"
tabcontrol1.TabPages.Add(tabpagep1);
```

How can I set the KEY of the tabpage1?

Comment: What do you mean by the "key"?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

There is nothing called as `TabPage Key`.

Key is the name of the `TabPage`. So, Setting the `Name` property of your `TabPage` should
work.

```
TabPage tabpagep1=new TabPage("");
tabpagep1.Name = "tp1";
tabpage1.text="netabpage1";
tabcontrol1.TabPages.Add(tabpagep1);
```

Later you can read it like

```
TabPage tp1 = tabcontrol1.TabPages["tp1"];
```

Answer (score 0):

The doc says it all : The **Name** property corresponds to the **key** for a Tab Page

**Key** is nothing but the **Name** of Tab Page

```
if (tabcontrol1.TabPages.ContainsKey("tabpagename")) 
{
   //select existing tab page by "Name" or say "Key"
  tabcontrol1.SelectTab("tabpagename");
}
else
{
   //create new tab page
  TabPage tabpagep1 = new TabPage("");
  tabpagep1.Name = "tabpagename";    
  tabcontrol1.TabPages.Add(tabpagep1);
}
```